# How to get a specific part of a website from urllib python

Tags: python, urllib

So, right now i have this very simple code just to gather information from the website https://generator.email/, here is the code

`import urllib.request
f = urllib.request.urlopen("https://generator.email/")
print(f.read())`

I just want the part of the page where the email is displayed but i have no clue where to even start with that. Anyone have any ideas?

when I run the program in wing ide it gives me a response of garbage, here is one of the responses:

cant post the full text here but you can see in this link, https://docs.google.com/document/d/18gIQZY1oFLd9eCpVbwabBrVwCrvRDBHuFOJgLD5n-S0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: My personal opinion is that your question is too broad, I have "no clue to even start" sometimes it means you have first to try harder and study the basics (HTML and Web programming basics too). Asking others to solve your problem  is IMHO not the way you should use SO. A good question is usually far far far more specific. IMHO

Comment: What you’re looking for is called “scraping”. You need to use a parser, or a higher-level library like Beautiful Soup, and then you can tell it how to find the part you’re looking for via XPath or css selectors or a chain of simple `find` calls. But until you know what any of that means, you won’t be able to do it, so you need to find some tutorial on “scraping with Beautiful Soup in Python” or similar and work through it.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it seems you need to study basics of Web Scraping. You can start either from BeautifulSoup or Scrapy to build a crawler. As far as your question is concerned, the email text part which you want can easily be achieved with BeautifulSoup and python requests module:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'https://generator.email/'
r = requests.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
data = soup.find_all('span', {"id":"email_ch_text"})
print(data[0].text)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You are the best!